# Pandas: Updating column values efficiently based on a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will summarize with a small example of what I am trying to do. Lets say we have a dataframe with two (out of roughly 15) of the columns represented below:

```
    change  period 
0    -1       1
1    -1       1
2    0.0      1
3    -1       1
4     1       2
5     1       2
6    0.0      2
7    0.0      2
8     1       2
9    -1       3

...
...
```

And this extends for around 25M data entries..
Essentially, I want to change each 0.0 under the change column in the dataframe to take the value of the direction within it's period (so either -1 or +1, which represent the directions), excluding the first entry in the period.

Currently I have the following I am running, but with so many data entries, I can't have it spending hours:

```py
def getPeriodDirection(period):
    val = df.loc[(df['period'] == period) & (df['change'] != 0.0) , 'change'].median()
    return val


df['change'] = df.apply(lambda row : getPeriodDirection(row['period']) if row['change'] == 0.0 else row['change'] , axis=1)
```

I tried several things, around using .locs but I just can't get it exactly how I need it. I tried the following:

```py
directionNoChange = df['change'].isin(range(0,1))

df.loc[directionNoChange, 'change'] = getPeriodDirection(df, df['period'])
```

This solution got me pretty close. I ended up having a dataframe with the original indexes when 'change' = 0.0, and have it updated with the correct value from the function. Based on the example, it would generate:

```
  change
2   -1
6    1
7    1
```

Next step would of been to substitute this value from the loc dataframe, on the original dataframe where the indexes lined up. But since I am kind of unfamiliar with the API, I am having a bunch of trouble!

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what value do you want instead of zeros..its not clear

Comment: I want the mean/median value of the 'change' column for that given period. So for period 1 it would be -1, for period 2 it would be 1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to replace the values of `0.0` with the median of the group, you can use `.mask` to convert the `0.0` values to `NaN`, then fill them with the `median`.

```
print(df)

   change  period
0    -1.0       1
1    -1.0       1
2     0.0       1
3    -1.0       1
4     1.0       2
5     1.0       2
6     0.0       2
7     0.0       2
8     1.0       2
9    -1.0       3

# mask takes a condition and fills the True values with NaN
print(df.change.mask(cond = df.change == 0))

0   -1.0
1   -1.0
2    NaN
3   -1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    1.0
9   -1.0
Name: change, dtype: float64

# use the other parameter similar to a fillna method
df['change'] = df.change.mask(cond = df.change == 0, other = df.groupby('period').change.transform('median'))

print(df)

   change  period
0    -1.0       1
1    -1.0       1
2    -1.0       1
3    -1.0       1
4     1.0       2
5     1.0       2
6     1.0       2
7     1.0       2
8     1.0       2
9    -1.0       3
```

Comment: Thanks! Really nice way of approaching the problem, was unaware of mask(). Quick question, when you group by period and calculate the median of the change column, how does it know which is it's period? Hope you understood the question

Comment: It knows by using the `.transform` function. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) state "Call func on self producing a DataFrame with transformed values and that has the same axis length as self." Since I am grouping the periods, the `.transform` knows which indices belong in which group. Therefore it knows where to put the median of each period.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this really helped me out!

Comment: You're welcome. If this satisfies your need, please select it as the correct answer and consider up-voting it